# How can I get value from vuex store using Mapstate?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Suddenly I cannot manage to get a value from the vuex store.
missing something trivial, but cannot see what ( me noob :(  )

In my component I import mapstate:

```
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
    mounted(){
        console.log('component mounted');
        
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState([
        'currentSpeler' ,'currentSpelerCard', 'currentGame'
        ]), 
    },
```

In tyhe Vue-panel of the chrome console I see that the value currentGame exists.

I can get my script working when I use:

```
console.log("currentGame.id ="+ this.$store.state.currentGame.id);
```

but when I use:

```
console.log("currentGame.id ="+ this.currentGame.id);
```

I get an error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

Does anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: Make sure you have initialised `currentGame` inside states with a default value!

Comment: Tried it...   That did not help unfortunately... 
But since `this.$store.state.currentGame` already worked I did not really expect this to be the solution..

Comment: Pls share the directory path where you have placed this  component

Comment: `resources/js/store/state.js`, component is `resources/js/components/MemoryGame.vue`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Vuex Docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper), the mapState helper returns an object by default.

You are importing your states in an array. You can use object instead of array.

```
computed: {
        ...mapState({
        currentSpeler: state => state. currentSpeler,
        currentSpelerCard: state => state.currentSpelerCard, 
        currentGame: state => state.currentGame
        }), 
    },
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. In another component I used the array notation without problems: 
computed{
...mapState([
            'cards' ])
    
    },

Comment: can you share your store files

Comment: This is the state.js: `export default{
    cards:[],
    games:[],
    token:localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
    currentGame:{},
    currentSpeler:{},
    currentSpelerCard:{},
} `
but in antother component I use `computed: {
        ...mapState([
        'currentSpeler' ,'currentSpelerCard', 'currentGame'
        ]), 
    }, ` and it works ike a charm. Also the `this.$store.state.currentGame.id` works fine. So i do not think something is wrong with the state...  Probably something trivial I forgot..

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to console log the currentGame and see what it looks like, then you can move on. My guess is that you somehow initialise the id parameter of currentGame while using the other component.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in this question. I tried to console log the currentGame itself:

 it also is undefined... Console says: 
`currentGame.id =undefined`

Also when I ask to log another object which is available in the store ( checked in chrome console, using Vue plugin, all store objects are shown...)

It looks like the mapState does not work, in this particular Memory.vue object.
Initialisation is exactly the dame as the other components.....

Comment: yeah, If you'd post the repo somewhere, I can have a look at it, but without it I really dont know what else could be wrong there atm.

also try to get it from parent component as a prop maybe.. or idk. sorry.

Comment: Thank you for thinking along. Just found out my STUPID mistake... ( aargh..) I had a second instance of Computed: { ...}  defined at the lower part in my script....
So the computed: declaration was overwritten...

Found out the error when I decide to copy the component part by part ..

Comment: yeah, been there :]

Answer (score 0):

Found the error...

I have declared computed : { ...}   twice.

```
computed: {
       ...mapState([
       'currentSpeler' ,'currentSpelerCard', 'currentGame',
       ]), 
 },
```

at the beginning of my script... and

```
computed: {
     
       sec(){
           if(this.totalTime.seconds < 10){
               return '0'+this.totalTime.seconds;
           }
           return this.totalTime.seconds;
       },
       min(){
           if(this.totalTime.minutes < 10){
               return '0'+this.totalTime.minutes;
           }
           return this.totalTime.minutes;
       }
   },
```

the memorygame logic at the end of my script... overwriting the mapState...

Very silly...* bangs head on desk *